# Why does calling my function throw a NameError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me out with the error in the code

```
a=input("Enter the number:")
kp(a)

def kp(num):
    for i in range(20):
        print(num*i)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? What are you using as input?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Aran-Fey The wrong order of function call and definition is not the only error in the code, the linked question is therefore not a duplicate

Comment: @FlyingTeller You mean because `a` is a string? That's perfectly valid. It may not be what the OP wants, but we can't say for sure without a [mcve]. I don't think it's worth reopening the question just to close it for a different reason.

Comment: sorry messed it up with the string. Now got the output after casting it into an int. Thanks!! @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 0):

You should define your function before its calling:

```
a=input("Enter the number:")

def kp(num):
    for i in range(20):
        print(num*i)
kp(a)
```